# Border-radius with percentage value not supported in Android Browsers

Tags: android, html, css, browser-support

Is there a known issue using % values in border radius on Android browsers?

I notice that when I use:

```
.element {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

The border radius seems to work on all mobile browsers, but when I use:

```
.element {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

The border radius does not apply on Android browsers.

Answer (score 11):

Yes there is: [check here, and click on known issues.](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius)

Here's what it says:

```
1. Android Browser 2.3 does not support % value for border-radius.

2. Border-radius does not work on fieldset elements in IE9.

3. The stock browser on the Samsung Galaxy S4 with Android 4.2 does not support the "border-radius" shorthand property but does support the long-hand properties for each corner like "border-top-left-radius".
```

What are you using the percentage value for? Please tell us, so we can further help you.

Now, since you are using it to make circles, there's a dirty hack you can use:

```
#circle {
  border-radius: 9999px; /* makes it a circle */
}
```

That should work fine.

Comment: I am using them to make circles

Comment: That dirty hack is awesome! Is pretty cross-browser compatible as well. Works in IE9. Didn't try in IE8, cause like my ex if something does me wrong I throw it to the curb.

Comment: @Gavin Haha - glad you liked it. I used it before in programs where I animated morphing squares into circles, and it wasn't totally practical for me to write `50%` or anything of such a nature.

Comment: the large-pixel-value workaround is great... even works on android 2.3 ;-) ... made it 999px though. Sufficient for my usecases.